# Reloading iframe in ASP.NET site from C# code

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, iframe

Trying to reload an iframe after C# has modified its attributes. Here's the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadFrame(Map) {
        document.getElementById(Map).contentDocument.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" placeholder="Zip code" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Find locations" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<iframe id="Map" runat="server"></iframe>
```

And when the button is clicked it runs this:

```
var zipCode = TextBox1.Text;
Map.Attributes.Add("src", "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+" + zipCode);        
browser.Document.InvokeScript("reloadFrame", new[] { "Map" });
```

However the line to reload the iframe doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using AJAX too? (or jQuery)  Otherwise, your Button1_Click event will make the whole page flip and your "reloadFrame" call will probably be unnecessary.  Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: No to AJAX, jQuery yes but not for this particular function. I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Currently the compiler won't accept the last line: browser.Document.InvokeScript... If I comment it out it all works fine but doesn't reload the iframe of course

Comment: When you click your "Find Locations" button, the page refreshes.  Right?  That doesn't reload your iFrame?

Comment: It will not compile with the last like there, I have to comment it out.

Comment: Yeah.  That last line is javascript, you can't run that in your C# code.  You could use a Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock() command to execute it client-side.

Comment: Would I just pass in the name of the JS function I want to run when it's called as an argument? ie. Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(reloadFrame);

Comment: So close. Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("whatev", "<script>\n reloadFrame('Map');\n </script>") http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. What is "Whatev"?

Comment: "Whatev" is a name for the script block. Then if you add more than one script block, you can tell them apart.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I just tried it, it still didn't show the map. It did print reloadFrame('Map'); to the page in plain text though...

Comment: Sorry, I revised my suggestion.  If you put a <script>  </script> block around it, then it will execute as jscript.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that it's not executing it but still nothing showing in the iframe. I can view the source and it shows that the src attribute for the iframe has been correctly added, I can even go to that url in a new tab and it loads fine. What could stop it from loading in the iframe here?

Comment: Turns out everything is fine, Google maps will not load in iframes unless it's the link code that they give you for a specific map... Everything else is perfect though, thanks everyone for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the src for the iFrame via inline code?

```
<iframe id="Map" runat="server" src='<%= (TextBox1.Text == "" ? "" : "https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!q=gnc+near%3A+" + zipCode) %>'></iframe>
```